# Write on JSON file and display the same on component in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular, typescript

project with 4 components 1. Login 2. Home(to view minute detail of Employee) 3. View(to show complete Details of Employee) and 4. Edit. Am already able to read Employee Details from .json file and display on the View in Detail component and View Component.

Now I want to change the details available in JSON file and display the same on View and ViewinDetail components.

My Employee.json is as follows:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "firstName": "Abhi",
        "lastName": "A B",
        "gender": "male",
        "age": 25,
        "email": "Abhi@gmail.com",
        "phoneNumber": 8888888888,
        "department": "IT",
        "address": "Bengaluru"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "firstName": "Amogh",
        "lastName": "A M",
        "gender": "male",
        "age": 25,
        "email": "Amogh@gmail.com",
        "phoneNumber": 8888888888,
        "department": "IT",
        "address": "Bengaluru"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "firstName": "Harsha",
        "lastName": "H A",
        "gender": "male",
        "age": 25,
        "email": "Harsha@gmail.com",
        "phoneNumber": 8888888888,
        "department": "IT",
        "address": "Bengaluru"
    }
]
```

My home.html is as follows:

```
<header>Welcome Home</header>
<br />
<div class="container panel panel-default" *ngFor="let employee of employeeList;">
        <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">{{employee.firstName}} {{employee.lastName}}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="col-xs-10">
                        <div class="row vertical-align">
                                <div class="col-xs-8 offset-md-2">
                                        <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                        First Name
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                        : {{employee.firstName}}
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                        Last Name
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                        : {{employee.lastName}}
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                        Gender
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                        : {{employee.gender}}
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                        Department
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                        : {{employee.department}}
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                                <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="viewEmployee(employee.id)">
                                                        View</button>&nbsp;
                                                <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="editEmployee(employee.id)">
                                                        Edit
                                                </button>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

My home.ts is as follows:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import employees from '../employeeDetails/employees.json';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router) { }
  public employeeList: {
    id: number;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    gender: string;
    age: number;
    email?: string;
    phoneNumber?: number;
    department: string;
  }[] = employees;
  // tslint:disable-next-line: use-lifecycle-interface
  ngOnInit(): void { }

  viewEmployee(id): any {
    this.router.navigateByUrl(`/view/${id}`);
  }

  editEmployee(i): any {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/edit');
  }
}
```

My view.html is as follows:

```
<header>View Page</header>
<br />
<div class="container panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">{{employee.firstName}} {{employee.lastName}}</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <div class="row vertical-align">
        <div class="col-xs-8 offset-md-2">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              First Name
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              : {{employee.firstName}}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              Last Name
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              : {{employee.lastName}}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              Gender
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              : {{employee.gender}}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              Age
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              : {{employee.age}}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              Email
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              : {{employee.email}}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              Phone Number
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              : {{employee.phoneNumber}}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              Department
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              : {{employee.department}}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="editEmployee()">
              Edit
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My view.ts is as follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import employees from '../employeeDetails/employees.json';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-view',
  templateUrl: './view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./view.component.css']
})
export class ViewComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
  public employeeList: {
    id: number;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    gender: string;
    age: number;
    email?: string;
    phoneNumber?: number;
    department: string;
  }[] = employees;
  employee;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
      const employeeId = params.id;
      this.employee = employees.filter((e) => e.id === +employeeId)[0];
    });
  }
  editEmployee(): any {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/edit');
  }
}
```

My edit.html is as follws:

```
<header>Edit Page</header>
<div class="container" style="margin-top:1%" action="/view">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword">LastName</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">

            <tr><label for="exampleInputGender">Gender : </label>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;<td><input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male" checked="checked">
                    <label for="male">Male</label><br></td> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <td><input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female">
                    <label for="female">Female</label></td>
            </tr>


        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputAge">Age</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPhoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPhoneNumber">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPhoneNumber">Address</label>
            <textarea type="textbox" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAddress"></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" (click)=editDetails()>
    </div>
</div>
```

My edit.ts is as follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import employees from '../employeeDetails/employees.json';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit',
  templateUrl: './edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit.component.css']
})
export class EditComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
  public employeeList: {
    id: number;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    gender: string;
    age: number;
    email?: string;
    phoneNumber?: number;
    department: string;
  }[] = employees;

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  editDetails(): any {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/edit');
  }
}
```

Please help, I don't have much idea how to proceed. I thought of editing the .json file but didn't know how to do it. Any other methods are also acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write into JSON file which you are storing in the project just by typescript.

I am assuming that you want to replicate a server and that's why you have stored a `json` locally and fetching the value in component.

To write to such JSON file, you need install something like [json-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server) and then make a `POST` call to the localhost server. That should give you the expected behavior.

To fetch the `json` data, you'll need make a `GET` call to the same `localhost` server

---

As mentioned in the comment, if you want to use `sesssionStorage`, you can simply save the json into the `ParentComponent` as

```
constructor(){
  sessionStorage.setItem('empList',employees);
}
```

then to use it `OtherComponents`, you can do:

```
ngOnInit(){
  const data = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('empList'));
  if (!!data){
     // there is no data in sessionStorage
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I have JSON file in sessionstorage and operate on that?

Comment: Can you show a piece of code, how JSON class is stored in the session storage.? It would be helpful, if you use the above code.

Comment: I don't want to replicate a server. Without much idea I worked on that

Comment: @Akash: please check updated answer. I would still not recommend you to use `sessionStorage`. Either explain more in the question about your use case or give my updated answer a try.

Comment: I have not used any parent components. All 4 are separate components. How to do that?

Comment: @Akash: Set the session value in `AppComponent` which will hold other components as its child.

Comment: I have not worked on the issue. I will let you know once it is done

Comment: @Akash : sure, just make sure to mark it as an answer so that it can be helpful to others as well